# Create google drive folder - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot call constructor

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';

require_once __DIR__.'/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$key = file_get_contents(__DIR__ .'/xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12');
    $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials( 'xxxx@gmail.com', array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'), $key);
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $client->setUseObjects(true);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'Invoices',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot call constructor in
>   /home/htdemosn/public_html/xxx/google-api-php-client/vendor/google/apiclient-services/Google/Service/Drive.php:75
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/htdemosn/public_html/xxx/quickstart.php(15):
>   Google_Service_Drive->__construct(Object(Google_Client)) #1 {main}
>   thrown in
>   /home/htdemosn/public_html/xxx/google-api-php-client/vendor/google/apiclient-services/Google/Service/Drive.php
>   on line 75

Want to create google folder and insert file into it, please give your ideas?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: try with this link
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder

Comment: Thanks, tried but it shows below error and I want the **$driveService** variable value in it

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in /home/htdemosn/public_html/xcode/quickstart.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/htdemosn/public_html/xcode/quickstart.php on line 13

Comment: Please follow this steps 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php

Comment: Yes followed the step. but got the below error
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: This application must be run on the command line. in /home/htdemosn/public_html/xcode/quickstart.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/htdemosn/public_html/xcode/quickstart.php on line 21
Is there any idea? did you tried these steps?